# Google Visualization Issue with Small Values in Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-api, google-visualization

Apparently Google Visualization Pie Charts don't like very small values. I've created a JSfiddle to demonstrate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/technotarek/YRKHd/

When you load the fiddle, you'll see the pie chart has four categories as one would expect from examining the JS in lines 6-13. Now, try changing the third value in line 13 of the JS from 5 to 1 and then run the fiddle. You'll see that it changes the label on the pie graph to a new label of "other". Can anyone figure out a way around that? (This is particularly problematic in my situation, because we use the label 'other' in some situations to represent a completely different group in the data.)

To satisfy the SO validator, here's my JS code from the fiddle:

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Race');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Percent');
    data.addRows(4);
    data.setValue(0, 0, 'Black, non-Hispanic');
    data.setValue(0, 1, 1370);
    data.setValue(1, 0, 'Hispanic');
    data.setValue(1, 1, 40);
    data.setValue(2, 0, 'White, non-Hispanic');
    data.setValue(2, 1, 537);
    data.setValue(3, 0, 'Suppressed Categories');
    data.setValue(3, 1, 5);

```
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
chart.draw(data, {
                    width: 650,
                    height: 500,
                    fontSize: 11,
                    chartArea:{
                            top:20,
                            left:100
                            },
                    colors:
                        [
                        '8d2300','FE9929','D95F0E','000000',                            ]
});
}      

google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "Other" category is created to hold all slices that are below the `sliceVisibilityThreshold` option's value in proportion to the total (default is 1/720).  When the "Suppressed Categories" value is 1, it is 1/1948 of the pie (far below the threshold), and so is grouped in the "Other" category.  You can manually set the `sliceVisibilityThreshold` option to whatever value you want (0 forces all slices to draw, regardless of their relative size):

```
chart.draw(data, {
    width: 650,
    height: 500,
    fontSize: 11,
    chartArea:{
        top:20,
        left:100
    },
    colors:['8d2300','FE9929','D95F0E','000000'],
    sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0
});
```

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/YRKHd/10/